# aws cli - How to query only ec2 on demand instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface, instance, aws-cli

`` aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=tag-key,Values=Name --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{Instance:InstanceId,Name:Tags[?Key==`Name`]|[0].Value,}' --output table ``

I've tried using this query but I don't know how to show only the on demand, or at least list it aside..

Comment: instance-lifesycle.. thats the column I want to see in the list or at least show the non spot (the on demand only)

Answer (score 3):

this query will give you non-spot instances:

```sh
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[?InstanceLifecycle!=`spot`].{Instance:InstanceId,Name:Tags[?Key==`Name`]|[0].Value}[][]' --output table
```

Comment: But the result is by instance id.
How do I add instance name?

Comment: aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[?InstanceLifecycle!=`spot`].[{Name:Tags[?Key==Name]|[0].Value}][][]'  --output table
This one didn't work to show instance name

Comment: You just need to use the same syntax as you had in your question, I updated query for you so it's now showing table with instanceId and Name tag. I hope this help :)

Comment: here you can find everything you need to fully understand JMESPath syntax:  https://www.doaws.pl/blog/2021-12-05-how-to-master-aws-cli-in-15-minutes/how-to-master-aws-cli-in-15-minutes

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the `InstanceLifecycle` value to appear in your output results, add it to `--query`:

`aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=tag-key,Values=Name --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{Instance:InstanceId,Name:Tags[?Key==`Name`]|[0].Value,Type:InstanceLifecycle}' --output table`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to learn it, only instance types (ex: `t2.micro`) are available.

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstanceTypes.html) says `supported-usage-class` filters you the usage class though.